# Is there a way of listing all the DoIts which have been done in a Smalltalk session?

Tags: logging, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

Is there a way of listing all the DoIts which have been done in a session in Pharo or Squeak as well as which workspaces they were done in?

Are the contents of workspaces also tracked, so they can be diffed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a file in the same directory as your image and with the same name as your image but with the extension ".changes".  This file contains all the source code and all the doit's you've performed.  Workspace text isn't tracked unless you execute it in which case it appears in the .changes file.

Comment: Is the changes file updated only when you save the workspaces? My test seems to indicate so.

Comment: The changes file is updated when you do doits and when you make changes in the browsers like changing methods, adding classes, removing classes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In a recent Squeak (at least 4.3), you can select the Extras menu at the top, and go to "Recover Changes". This asks you how far back you want to look; for "stuff I've done this session" that's probably the topmost choice.

That will give you a `ChangeList` showing all the `doIt`s (and some other stuff) up to the last time you saved the image. (The `ChangeList` gets all its info from the .changes file that David Buck mentions.)

However, this will not tell you in which `Workspace` these were evaluated. `Workspace`s do not version their contents.

Comment: I checked Pharo 1.4 and it also this option. Thx